# Method runs multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown, keyup

I'm trying to get products when user done with typing. But when user done typing, method runs multiple times not once.

If user type "apple" `fetchProducts` method run five times and send 5 ajax request. How can I reduce at once (unless you user start to search different product)

```
$(document).on("keyup keydown", 'input.select2-search__field', function (e) {

    let timer,
        interval = 2000,
        searchText = this.value;

    if (e.type == "keyup") {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(fetchProducts, interval);
    }
    if (e.type == "keydown") {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }

    function fetchProducts() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "../../../products/get-by-select-search",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $("meta[name=csrf-token]").attr("content")
            },
            data: {search: searchText},
            success: function (response) {
                product.find('option').remove();
                product.select2({
                    theme: "classic",
                    data: response
                })
                    .val(null)
                    .trigger("change");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Use debounce function from lodash.

Comment: Move the `timer` variable outside the function

Comment: If you type `apple`, then you run `fetchProducts` 5 times (there are 5 `keyup` events). How would you know when someone is done typing in a product?

Comment: @tymeJV Ops sorry, I fixed the question

Comment: @Ivar yes I'm trying to use that answer but doesn't work for me

Comment: @HasanTıngır Did you read the second answer as well?

Comment: You need to have the `timer` variable outside the handler, or else it gets reset on every key event. The dupe link has, hence it works.

Comment: @LGSon ohh you're right! I was thinking way why soktinpk said that...

Comment: @Chris So then why we need the built-in _"Close as duplicate"_? ... and I did more than just closed it, I added a comment telling what was wrong and how to fix it.